# Is "recorded history" redundant?

Tags: word-usage, redundancy

I've heard many times phrases like "this particular thing has been a fact of life throughout recorded history".

In fact there is [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recorded_history):

> Recorded history or written history is a historical narrative based on
>   a written record or other documented communication.

That seems to contradict this widely accepted definition of history stating that history is "the study of the past as it is described in written documents". And "prehistory" (before history) is considered "events occurring before written record".

> History (from Greek ἱστορία, historia, meaning "inquiry, knowledge
>   acquired by investigation") is the study of the past as it is
>   described in written documents. Events occurring before written record
>   are considered prehistory.

From this Wikipedia article quoting this sources:

> Joseph, Brian (Ed.); Janda, Richard (Ed.) (2008). The Handbook of
>   Historical Linguistics.  Blackwell Publishing (published 30 December
>   2004). p. 163. ISBN 978-1-4051-2747-9.
>
> "History Definition". Retrieved 21 January 2014.
>
> "What is History & Why Study It?". Retrieved 21 January 2014

So if history implies records, and the time before writting was invented is considered prehistory, why is "recorded history" so widely used?

Comment: Yes, it's redundant by definition, if *history* is used in that technical sense. However, one can also "study ... the past" by examining artifacts or by reviewing oral tradition ('spoken' history), neither of which requires writing. Note that it's hard to justify calling something in the past *prehistory* just because it wasn't written down - e.g. some of the work anyone did yesterday.

Comment: I personally don't equate 'history' with 'the written record'. To me things that occurred before writing are also historical, just a little more difficult to learn about. 'Recorded history' doesn't sound pleonastic to me, just an emphasis about events occurring and we know about them by writing. But there is the academic distinction of prehistory (archeology) vs history (written) (as you note). So technically 'recorded history' is a little redundant, but doesn't usually feel that way (if my perception is common).

Comment: You're being selective in your choice of definitions. [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/history) has the broader definition (1) 'The study of past events, particularly in human affairs.' (amongst others).

Comment: My pet peeve is use of the cliche, "never in recorded history," which returns about 64,700 hits on Google, my favorite of which from the first page is, "Never in recorded history has any subject been discussed as much, and understood as little, as vacuum systems and their effects on carpet cleaning." Hahahaha! "Never in recorded history" is also a favorite phrase of politicians and bad journalists, who somehow never seem to document their claims. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a peeve

Comment: A lot of history is taken from oral traditions, or derived after the fact by examining artifacts.  "Recorded history" refers to accounts that were authored reasonably soon after the described events occurred.

Comment: If I have a history of jumping to conclusions, does that mean each leap must be recorded? Isn't then a record of such events "recorded history" as distinct from those times that the jumping was not recorded and hence "unrecorded history"?

Comment: @MarkHubbard My pet peeve is "this is the first time X has happened since..." So not really the first time then.

Comment: @LaconicDroid: Do you also have a problem with statements like “The leopard is the smallest of the ‘big cats’.” (so, not the smallest cat), “This past month was the warmest January ever in the Northern Hemisphere.” (but not the warmest *month* ever), and “Jane is the tallest woman.” (but not the tallest person)? If **B** is a subset of **A**, it makes sense to apply statistics (min, max, average, etc.) to the elements of **B**.  There’s nothing contradictory about “Lyndon B. Johnson was the tallest president since Abraham Lincoln” or “2020 will be the first Olympics in Japan since 1998.”

Comment: @Scott "Smallest of the big cats" is perfectly fine as "big cats" is a countable group. "Warmest January ever" is perfectly fine as it's comparing the set of all Januaries. That is not the same as "he's the first person to run the marathon under 2hrs 15 mins since Dave in 2013". My old Computer Science professor used to tell us you can substitute "not" any place "virtually" is used. The same goes for "The first since..." which can be replaced with "not the first...". I just find it an annoying and heavily overused turn of phrase.

Comment: @LaconicDroid: As far as I know, the number of people who have run the marathon since Dave ran it in 2013 is countable and finite, so I don’t see the difference. I also don’t understand what countability has to do with it — even an uncountably infinite set can have a minimum and maximum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of definitions of ***[history](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/history)*** is:

> The whole series of past events connected with a particular person or
>   thing.
>   *‘the history of the Empire’*

Clearly, some of these events can be recorded, and some not. If there was no one recording these events at the time they took place, and we have learned about them through other means, they are still *history* - but they are not *recorded history*. Consider for example the history of the Moon (to take an extreme example).

Logic apart, the phrase ***never in recorded history*** is a figure of speech, similar to *since time immemorial* or *for as long as I can remember* and such. I don't think any of these are meant to be taken literally.

It's worth noting that the idiom *since time immemorial* is defined by the [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/since+time+immemorial) as:

> since a very long time ago. (**Literally**, since time before **recorded
>   history**.)

*(emphasis added by me)*

Go argue with that.

Comment: _auld lang syne_

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on how you define "history." If your definition states that to be history someone must have preserved the information, then yes, it is redundant. But one could also look at history as anything that has ever happened. Of those events that have happened, only a small percentage of them are witnessed, remembered, and eventually recorded. 
Also, it depends on what you mean by recorded. Do oral or pictoral methods count, or must it be written? If other methods don't count, why not? What makes them different?